# Optimisation with list solution: compiler error

Tags: haskell, sbv

I'm trying to solve an optimisation problem with [sbv](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/sbv-8.6) in Haskell, but get a compiler error.

The solution is a list of values, and I have a function to check the solution is valid (the constraint), and a function to calculate a number to minimize.

I get this compiler error on my minimal example:

```
/home/t/sbvExample/Main.hs:28:5: error:
    • No instance for (S.SymVal S.SBool)
        arising from a use of ‘Sl.length’
    • In the expression: Sl.length xs
      In an equation for ‘toNum’: toNum xs = Sl.length xs
   |
28 |     Sl.length xs
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Here's the code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-} 
module Main (main) where

import qualified Data.SBV.List as Sl
import qualified Data.SBV as S


main :: IO ()
main = do
    result <- S.optimize S.Lexicographic help
    print result


help :: S.SymbolicT IO ()
help = do
    xs :: S.SList S.SBool <- S.sList "xs"
    S.constrain $ isValid xs
    S.minimize "goal" $ toNum xs


isValid :: S.SList S.SBool -> S.SBool
isValid xs =
    Sl.length xs S..> 0


toNum :: S.SList S.SBool -> S.SInteger
toNum xs =
    Sl.length xs
```

So in this silly minimal example I would expect a list containing one item.

For convenience I put it on Github, so build it with:

```
git clone https://github.com/8n8/sbvExample
cd sbvExample
stack build
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting this error message because [there is no instance of SymVal for `SBool`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/sbv-8.6/docs/Data-SBV.html#t:SymVal), only for `Bool`, and `S.length` expects a `S.SList` of `SymVal` values:

```
length :: SymVal a => SList a -> SInteger
```

You can fix this by changing `toNum` and `isValid` to accept y `S.SList Bool`, and changing the type of `xs` to `S.SList Bool`:

```
help :: S.SymbolicT IO ()
help = do
    xs :: S.SList Bool <- S.sList "xs"
    S.constrain $ isValid xs
    S.minimize "goal" $ toNum xs

isValid :: S.SList Bool -> S.SBool
isValid xs =
    Sl.length xs S..> 0

toNum :: S.SList Bool -> S.SInteger
toNum xs =
    Sl.length xs
```

Your `isValid` and `toNum` functions are also overly specialized, since they only require a `SymVal` class constraint. The following is more general and still compiles:

```
isValid :: S.SymVal a => S.SList a -> S.SBool
toNum :: S.SymVal a => S.SList a -> S.SInteger
```

**EDIT**

Weren't it for `toNum` failing to typecheck, you would have also seen that `S.sList` also doesn't typecheck, since its type signature has a `SymVal` constraint on the type parameter of the returned `S.SList`:

```
sList :: SymVal a => String -> Symbolic (SList a)
```

Deleting `isValid` and `toNum`, and only keeping the `S.sList` constructor:

```
help = do
    xs :: S.SList S.SBool <- S.sList "xs"
    return ()
```

throws this error:

```
• No instance for (S.SymVal S.SBool)
    arising from a use of ‘S.sList’
```

Which, in my opinion, tells a bit more about the actual issue. It just goes to show that a minimal example can sometimes be even more minimal, and therefore more helpful.

Answer (score 3):

From [the documentation for `SList`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/sbv-8.6/docs/Data-SBV.html#t:SList):

> Note that a symbolic list is *not* a list of symbolic items, that is, it is not the case that `SList a = [a]`, unlike what one might expect following haskell lists/sequences. An `SList` is a symbolic value of its own, of possibly arbitrary but finite length, and internally processed as one unit as opposed to a fixed-length list of items.

So if you're going to use an `SList`, then you need to use it with regular `Bool`s, not `SBool`s.